# Browser extension to export Data into csv file?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, browser-extension

I'm currently working on a browser extension that lets me take data from a specific web page and i want to download it in a csv file.

Now i got all the data saved up on a click, but when i try to use chrome.downloads.download() it constantly tells me "cannot read property of undefined" and marks that function. what am I doing wrong?

This is what my manifest.json looks like:

```
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Data Downloader",
  "description": "Download a csv file with data from MDR",
  "version": "1.0",

  "icons": {
    "48": "icon.png"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "<all_urls>","downloads"
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

and this is my popup.html which is working fine:

```
<html>
  <body style="width: 300px">
    Open <a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">this page</a> and then 
    <button id="clickme">click me</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and thats my javascript that gets called when I click on the popup button

```
    const copy = [];
    const array1 = [];
    const array2 = [];

    //console.log("1");
    //var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];  
    //var reader = new FileReader();  
    //reader.readAsText(file);
    
    //reader.onload=function(){  
     //   var textall=this.result;
        //alert(_table);
        //var parsedDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(textall, 'text/html');
        //console.log("2");
        //console.log(parsedDoc);
        
        for (let i=0; i<6; i++) {
            array1.push(document.getElementsByClassName("horse_basics tab_padding")[i]);
        }
        
        console.log(array1);
        array1.forEach(function(item) {
            array.push(item.children[1].children[1].innerText);
            array.push(item.children[5].children[1].innerText);
            array.push(item.children[9].children[1].innerText);
            array.push(item.children[13].children[1].innerText);
        });
        
        for (let i=6; i<8; i++){
            array2.push(document.getElementsByClassName("horse_basics tab_padding")[i]);
        }
        array2.forEach(function(item){
            array.push(item.children[1].children[1].innerText);
            array.push(item.children[5].children[1].innerText);
            array.push(item.children[9].children[1].innerText);
            array.push(item.children[13].children[1].innerText);
            array.push(item.children[17].children[1].innerText);
            array.push(item.children[21].children[1].innerText);
            array.push(item.children[25].children[1].innerText);
            array.push(item.children[29].children[1].innerText);
        });

        array.push(document.getElementsByClassName("horse_disciplines tab_padding")[0].children[1].children[1].innerText);
        array.push(document.getElementsByClassName("horse_disciplines tab_padding")[0].children[5].children[1].innerText);
        array.push(document.getElementsByClassName("horse_disciplines tab_padding")[0].children[9].children[1].innerText);
        array.push(document.getElementsByClassName("horse_disciplines tab_padding")[0].children[13].children[1].innerText);
        
        array.forEach(function(item) {
            var newItem = item.match(/\d+/)[0];
            copy.push(newItem);
        });
        alert(copy);
        var names = document.getElementsByClassName("horse_name").innerText;
        var blob = new Blob(copy, {type: "text/plain"});
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        
        chrome.downloads.download({
            url: url, 
            filename: "csv/file"+names
        });
```

the last part doesn't work and i can't figure out why... can you help me?

I do know that i have to restrict the action to what it matches (only that specific page I want to use it for) but that can't be the problem rn, right?

Thanks for your help!